# NaCL: Encrypt file to multiple recipients

Tags: encryption, cryptography, file-encryption

I am trying to understand the [Networking And Cryptography Library](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/) (NaCL).

Consider i have a file that i want to send to multiple recipients. PGP or S/MIME supports multiple recipients by encrypting the file with a single symmetric key and encrypting this symmetric key with the public keys of the recipients. is this task easily achieved with NaCL as well? How? Thanks for hints.

**Update**
One idea i had is to do it similar to pgp. Calculate the exchange keys of my own private key and the public keys of the recipients. Create one symmetric key. Encrypt file file symmetric key. Encrypt symmetric key with each exchange key. send encrypted file and encrypted symmetric key to recipient.

The main reason for this: i want to upload the encrypted file only once to a server where the recipients can download them.

Comment: Are you looking for code using NaCL?

Comment: @raz anything that helps me to nail the multiple recipient problem

Comment: The saltpack format fits that description: https://saltpack.org/encryption-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual format of NaCL's output is not completely specified -- or, rather, it is specified as being the raw output from some cryptographic primitives (as described [there](http://cr.yp.to/highspeed/naclcrypto-20090310.pdf)). The format is thus non-extensible and does not include any feature supporting multiple recipients. Ability to send a message to multiple recipient appears to be a functionality that has been sacrificed on the altar of simplicity.

If you want to use NaCL and still send a single message to multiple recipients without duplicating the bulk of the data, then you must design your own format, basically doing this:

- You generate a random secret key *K*.
- You use *K* to encrypt the message (with [`crypto_secretbox`](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/secretbox.html)).
- You encrypt *K* as if it was the "message" with [`crypto_box`](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html).

But then you are defining your own protocol, built over existing primitives. This is the exact kind of things that NaCL was meant to prevent. Or, said otherwise, if you are back to doing your own protocol design then why would you use NaCL ? And, in any case, you would be on your own, both for the security analysis *and* the implementation (since you would not interoperate with anybody else).

If what you need is what [OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) provides, then use OpenPGP.

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks for explanation. I am actually already using OpenPGP, but the message overhead is massive. NaCL produces smaller messages, and that was what i was looking for.

Comment: Does OpenPGP provide a way to add recipients *retroactively*?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need your own protocol, as Tom explained. If you decide to do this, you should sign the message (with `cryto_sign()`).

When Alice sends a message to Bob, she wants to make sure than an active eavesdropper Eve does not alter the message. Therefore you have authentication (which `crypto_box()` takes care of automatically). When Alice sends the message to Bob and Charlie, she furthermore wants to make sure Bob does not alter the message and pass it on to Charlie. Then authentication is no longer sufficient, you want signatures.